# Will bad things happen if I control the content of $_POST?

Tags: php, forms, post, authentication

In my days of writing web applications, I'm missing a simple way for a PHP script to direct to another PHP script while passing along data **without using the URL**

Browsers can pass data invisibly to a PHP script using the $_POST array. So I'm devising a script that will dump the contents of $_SESSION["POST"] into the $_POST array to mimic the passing of post data, then clears $_SESSION["POST"].

For instance, a page X contains a login form. Page X directs to page Y to validate the data. Page Y discovers that the login information is incorrect, and redirects back to page X - which now displays the error message "Login information incorrect" from $_POST.

Am I crazy for missing this feature? Is there some other method of doing this easily that I'm missing?

Please respond with anything that can be helpful.

Comment: Perhaps instead of redirecting to another page you could just include that PHP file?

Comment: Do you plan to modify the current `$_POST` array and then include() another script? Or do you plan to issue an redirect with POST data? (auto-submitting form)

Comment: Since this is an MVC application all pages have the same access point. I intent to check for data in $_SESSION["POST"] at each page load and dump that into the $_POST array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the session. On page X, you'd put the data into the session. On page Y, you'd validate the data and handle the redirect. You can put your error message into the session too.

The session persists between requests, so it's the perfect place to store that kind of data.

**EDIT**

OK, I'd do things with session variables, but if you want to avoid that you do have a few other options I can think of besides posting:

1. You can use files on the server (such as temporary files). Use the user's session key to identify which file is theirs, and you can read and write whatever data you care to it.
2. You can put the data in a database. That would work too.

Of course neither of those is a true post. If you want a true post, you have another two options.

1. First, you can return the data to the page in a hidden form, and use JavaScript to trigger a POST. This is simple to do, but it requires the data to pass through the browser. This means you'd have to take care that a user didn't change the data, and the user would have to have JavaScript on. You can checksum the data to ensure it isn't modified, but the JavaScript problem is unsolvable.
2. Another way to do it would be to take the user out of the equation entirely. When the user submits to page A, page A could make a POST to page B, check the response, and then redirect the user to the proper place. This would be just like if you had to make a JSON or SOAP call to a 3rd party service, except you control that service. It's been a little while, but I believe that [HttpRequest](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.httprequest.php) is the class to use to do this.

It would be ideal if that URL you check with returns a simple answer ("true", "false", "yes", "no", "good", "bad", whatever), but as long as you can tell by the response whether they were successful or not, you can do it.

Now I should note that I'd agree with mvds, this sounds like a function that should be included in page A so that it can do all the work but the code can be shared with other pages. Having page A post to page B and then redirect to A or C seems unnecessarily complex. Page A can easily accomplish all this. I read your comment on his answer, but it seems there should be another way to accomplish this.

Comment: What I want is to pass data from one page to another, **not** to save data in session for ever. If I simply use the session for that I would have to clear out the used variables from session every time I use them. Wouldn't it be simpler to just dump everything in `$_POST`, which clears itself after the page has been displayed?

Comment: @Codemonkey Maybe I´m missing something, but I fail to see the problem; whether it´s a multiple-page registration form or a simple login form, you can easily unset that specific session variable after successful registration / login / etc.

Comment: The point of the question was a method of passing data from one PHP script to another without having to manage session variables. Easy or not, it adds up to a lot of code. In my opinion keeping code to a minimum is good. Thanks for the answer, but what I'm looking for is not really the obvious methods rather than information regarding the consequences of doing it my way. For instance, is there a good reason for not doing it my way?

Comment: Your solution number 2:2 is the one I'm suggesting, but why go through so much trouble using HttpRequest when I can set the $_POST variables myself?

Answer (score 0):

Abstract the performed actions to functions and/or classes, and the need for such kludges will vanish. Concrete: both page X and Y could call the same function to validate the posted login data.

Page X redirecting to page Y to do validation means handing back control to the client, while you could (and should) validate the data right away.

Comment: Everything in my application is abstracted to classes and methods. That doesn't change anything about my problem.

Comment: I presume page Y then only does a call like validate($_POST)? Why not do that call from page X?

Comment: Not that simple. Page X is a function called login in my userpanel controller. The function that handles validation is the function login in my user controller. Since methods are accessed by URL, **and** since I want to separate business logic from the template, I do it this way.